# How can I obtain the number of times a number appears in a queue (Java)?

Tags: java, queue

So let's say we have a [queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) that can store any integer inside it.

What I needed to do (for a test), was write a function that would create (and return) a new queue without leaving the original one changed.

**You *could* change it, but at the end of the function it would have to be as it was in the beginning**

Let's assume that the only methods in [class Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) are:

- insert/add
- remove
- peek
- isEmpty (returns True if queue is empty)

In the new queue we would have each integer and after it the number of times it appeared in the first queue.

Aside from the initial queue I could use: Stack(s), Array(s), new Queue(s) and possibly LinkedList(s).

**Writing new functions can be done as well.**

The straight up solution (I guess) would be to copy the first queue in any method, and then use while(!isEmpty) and a counter for the number which would then be added to the desired queue and removed from the copied one.

I don't have this written down at the moment but I can't really think of a cleaner and more efficient method of doing this, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Look for this ready solution: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-function-that-counts-the-number-of-times-a-given-int-occurs-in-a-linked-list/

Comment: The given solution is fit for a LinkedList, rather than a queue, but thanks anyway.

Comment: What do you mean? `LinkedList` is actually a `Queue`. `Queue` is an interface, you cannot have its instances, and `LinkedList` implicitly implements a `Queue` interface through a `Deque` interface.

Comment: (I know it is, but the point of this question was to use only the Queue methods, without the "deeper" LinkedList ones)
In any case in that solution they dont pass the queue to the linkedlist

Comment: what other methods than `Queue` has did you see there?

Comment: By the way did you try to do anything by your own?

Comment: it uses `while (current != null)` which is not something you can use only in queue.

Also, aside from what I mentioned, I tried something which was incorrect due to the way I attempted to copy the queues.

Comment: `current` is a `Node`, the ones you need to calculate. And that class is implemented there as well.

Comment: Yeah, `current` is a `Node`, but the point is that if you wish to solve it that way you need to convert the whole `Queue` into a `LinkedList`

Answer (score 1):

You're probably able to come up with a better solution with some time, but this is what I did:

```
public static Queue<Integer> countQueue(Queue<Integer> q) {
    LinkedList<Integer> valuesList = new LinkedList<>();
    // since we can't iterate on the Queue
    // we remove the head element
    while(!q.isEmpty()) {
        int x = q.remove();
        valuesList.add(x);
    }

    LinkedList<Integer> nonRepeated = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Integer> timesCount = new LinkedList<>();

    while(!valuesList.isEmpty()) {
        int value = valuesList.remove();
        q.add(value); // get the original queue back
        int index = nonRepeated.indexOf(value);
        if (index == -1) {
            nonRepeated.add(value);
            timesCount.add(1);
        } else {
            timesCount.set(index, timesCount.get(index)+1);
        }
    }
    Queue<Integer> output = new ArrayDeque<>();
    while(!nonRepeated.isEmpty()) {
        output.add(nonRepeated.remove());
        output.add(timesCount.remove());
    }

    return output;
}
```

If you're interested on creating a method to get the Queue's size, this might be one of the simplest solutions:

```
public static int getQueueSize(Queue<Integer> q) {
    int i=0;
    Queue<Integer> backupQueue = new ArrayDeque<>(); 
    while(!q.isEmpty()) {
        i++;
        backupQueue.add(q.remove());
    }
    while(!backupQueue.isEmpty())
        q.add(backupQueue.remove());
    return i;
}
```

Whenever using Queues, Stacks and etc., you'll need to pay attention to the data structure's paradigm, such as FIFO(First in First out) and LIFO(Last in First out), which will dictate how you should iterate on the structure.

Comment: How would queue.size be implemented?

Comment: Also, I didn't quite understand this line:

`int index = nonRepeated.indexOf(valuesArray[i]);`

Comment: I changed the code a bit so there is no need to get the size of the original queue. That line is needed so we can check whether the value has already been added to the `nonRepeated` Linked List. `LinkedList.indexOf` returns the index of the first occurrence of the element we're searching. If the element hasn't already been added, `indexOf` will return -1 and, in that case, we need to add the element and say that until this moment it appeared 1 time.  If it's been added, we'll know where it is on `nonRepeated` and we can increment its timeCount.

Comment: Isn't `valuesList` supposed to be a `Queue`?


Also assuming I'm using `Node<T>`, and I can't use `.indexOf`, how would i solve this problem? By writing a `inList/indexOf` function?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be one, but since we're only accessing the head element of it, therefore following FIFO, it could be declared as a Queue. `Queue<Integer> valuesQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();` is probably better. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

Idea: iterate through queue and re-add the elements to it as you do. Keep a map to store the counts of each element. Then convert the map into a queue.

Something like this (untested):

```
public Queue<Integer> count(Queue<Integer> input) {
  int size = input.size();
  Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      Integer element = input.remove(); // take from front of queue.
      if (!counts.contain(element)) {
          counts.put(element, 1);
      } else {
          counts.put(element, counts.get(element) + 1);
      }
      input.add(element); // now it's in the back of the queue.
  }

  // convert map to queue.
  Queue<Integer> output = new Queue<>();
  for (Integer key : counts.keySet()) {
      output.add(key);
      output.add(counts.get(key));
  }
  return output;
```

Note that the output won't contain the integers in the same order... But maintaining order was not part of the problem statement. If it is, you can think of other data structures to keep your counts in.

Comment: Using `for` loops is something I thought of as well, however, assuming that we don't have `queue.size()` implemented and that we need to write it, how would we do so without changing the input's size?

Comment: If you cannot obtain the queue's size, you'll have to iterate through it. One way is to iterate thru the queue and copy it to another queue as you keep count, and then put the elements of the copy back into the original one.

Comment: using a `while(!isEmpty)` loop?

Comment: yep, exactly!  :)

Comment: Another way to do the for loop without knowing the queue size is to add a "sentinel" value and then check for referential equality. Because Java only interns Integers up to 128, your sentinel value can be any integer above 128. This approach is a little hacky but would be much faster than the others proposed, since you only iterate through the input queue once.